# Restrict access to GCE HTTP(S) load balancer by request attribute or URL path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-armor

Is there some straightforward way to restrict user access to Google Compute Engine HTTP(S) load balancer by request attribute or URL? In case if a single request attribute can have hundreds of values that match, so requests that fulfill the required filter can pass to a backend.

Authentication is not what can be used there, so [Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) is not an option.

Cloud Armor seems to be in beta (and it's [custom expressions](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference) are in private beta). Also, it's not clear how it would bill filtered incoming requests: incoming requests charge for Cloud Armor is at [$0.75 per million HTTP(S) requests](https://cloud.google.com/armor/pricing). Is that including those requests being blocked by the custom rule? If it does, then it's pretty much easy to make GCP owner spent lots of money by just sending requests to the load balancer.

Google Compute Engine HTTP(S) load balancer has a [url-map](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map), which can do the trick, but it's [limited](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#url_maps) and seems to be difficult in my case (it's better for me to use request attributes, not the URL path). Also, it suffers the same billing issue as Cloud Armor do if you enable [user-defined request headers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/user-defined-request-headers), which priced at [$0.75 per million HTTP(S) requests](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#user-defined_request_headers_and_charges). So it's pretty much easy to make GCP owner spent lots of money by just sending requests to the load balancer.

So is there some straightforward way to restrict user access to Google Compute Engine HTTP(S) load balancer by request attribute or URL without a risk of being overcharged?

Comment: Did you find a proper solution for this?

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman I wrote a python script which gets (from CloudSQL) a list of paths that should have user-defined headers to be enabled. Then it fills a template of a load balancer config (JSON) with hostPath blocks 50 paths each. Last it applies that JSON with compute engine API (googleapiclient).

Comment: Also, there're some paths that have to be processed, but w/o user-defined headers set. So they're processed the same way as before, just hostPath blocks lead to another backend. And all the other requests pass to an empty backend (compute engine group w/o instances), that gives 502 code.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing without using Cloud Armor might be using [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview). It basically reads headers meant to identify users and authenticates them.

From your question, I'm under the impression that you're sending your own:

> In case if a single request attribute can have hundreds of values that match.

The thing with IAP is that, it only evaluates a [custom set of headers](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto#getting_the_users_identity_with_signed_headers) (that aren't yours) and you have to include and sign them in your request.

As a side note on the prices you mentioned, using *user-defined request headers* will only be charged when Cloud Armor [is not enabled](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#user-defined_request_headers_and_charges):

> If a backend service does **not** have a Google Cloud Armor policy associated with it, the charges are $0.75 per million HTTP(S) requests sent to those backend services that use the user-defined request headers feature.

Using these of course has an impact on billing and operational overhead since you need to validate them in your own backends.

Finally, although it seems that Cloud Armor is meant to address this specific use case, you might want to try and ask for this feature to be available directly in the HTTP(S) load balancer. [Here is a link to the feature request on Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=1162611).

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, but authentication is not what can be used there, so IAP is not an option.